# Black bar at the bottom in IOS6 instead UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I have two viewController (A,B), when I launch my app my root is a viewController A. He has an UitableView and an UITabBarController at the bottom. When I click in my UitableView I go to my viewController B.

My issue is that when I arrive in my viewController B, I have a black bar at the bottom of my view as if my UITabBarController stay, but I don't think it's that because I have the issue only on IOS 6.

And I don't want to see a UITabBarController in my viewController B, I want to have a simple view with a UiWebView but she doesn't go at the bottom.

In my viewController B in `viewWillAppear` I do `[self._tabBarControllerArticle.tabBar setHidden:YES];`

I have IOS 6/7 Deltas with Delta Y (20 or -20) with all components in my viewController B.

The result are good for IOS 7.

I don't know how can I resolve that.

Comment: Can you post an image of your situation?

Comment: I would like but I can't because I'm to young here @TotumusMaximus

Comment: A representation of the behaviour then? Aka something without actual details of the app, just shapes and lines so we can see what is happening and where (a drawn image in paint f.e.). This to improve the quality of our answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When click on table cell call hideTabBar as given below

```
  - (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
 {
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
    }
}

[UIView commitAnimations];   
}

 - (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
 {       
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", view);

    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

    } 
    else 
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
    }
}

[UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Show again when again come to the controller A again.

Comment: Thank you very very very much, that's work!!! Why [self._tabBarControllerArticle.tabBar setHidden:YES]; doesn't work for IOS 6 ? Yet I work in the same UITabBarController.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, sorry

Comment: When I'm come back to my viewController A, I have a white bar between my tableview and my UITabBarController, how can I solve that ? How can I calculate the number 431 for all the screen size ? Thank you